# I'm Using Bitmap inside a Timer tick event and everything goes very slow how can i solve it?

Tags: c#, winforms

In form1 top I did:

```
private volatile bool _workersEnabled;
private ConcurrentQueue<Bitmap> _imageBuffer;
Thread threadA;
Thread threadB;
```

Then in the constructor:

```
_workersEnabled = false;
_imageBuffer = new ConcurrentQueue<Bitmap>();

threadA = new Thread(CaptureScreensEntryPoint);
threadB = new Thread(ConsumeScreensEntryPoint);
```

Then in the button click event:

```
private void StartRecording_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ffmp.Start("test.avi", 25);
    _workersEnabled = true;
    threadA.Start();
    threadA.Start();

    //Disable the button, so we eliminate the possibility to start this twice (would throw an exception anyway).
    StartRecording.Enabled = false;
}
```

Then after it I added:

```
private void CaptureScreensEntryPoint()
{
    while(_workersEnabled)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)ScreenCapture.CaptureScreen(true);

        //Just add it to the queue.
        _imageBuffer.Enqueue(bitmap);

        //Wait a bit
        Thread.Sleep(40);
    }
}

private void ConsumeScreensEntryPoint()
{
    while (_workersEnabled)
    {
        Bitmap workItem = null;
        if (_imageBuffer.TryDequeue(out workItem))
        {
            ffmp.PushFrame(workItem);
            workItem.Dispose();
        }

        //Also wait a bit here. Don't want to eat up the entire processor.
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

The exception is on the `threadA.Start();`:

> ThreadStateException : Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart

```
System.Threading.ThreadStateException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233056
  Message=Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Thread.StartupSetApartmentStateInternal()
       at System.Threading.Thread.Start(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Threading.Thread.Start()
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.Form1.StartRecording_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Form1.cs:line 152
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Yeah, do it on a worker thread. Let it push the frame asynchronously. You may also want to push frame requests into a queue in a worker thread and just let it do it's job (when there's something to do).

Comment: marceln can you show me an example how to do it with a backgroundworker and queue or without a queue ?

Comment: See answer below. It's not a background worker, it's something simpler.

Comment: You won't be needing the timer anymore. Just fire up the workers and let them do their stuff.

Comment: Another solution to the problem, [use a different type of timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx). I am assuming timer1 is a `System.Forms.Timer`, using a `System.Threading.Timer` would make it happen on a different thread and not tie up the UI message pump. (this is basically the same answer as what the two existing answers say, just a way of implementing the separate thread)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Indeed, much less code that way. But the FPS would be reduced if `ffmp.PushFrame` is too time consuming. I guess it needs to be benchmarked.

Comment: Edited my question now with the new code and the exception i get please look at it . Thanks .

Comment: Are you sure StartRecording_Click isn't called twice somehow? Maybe you call it manually somewhere?

Comment: Oh, got it. There was an error in my code, which I corrected. You're calling `threadA.Start` twice. Replace the second occurrence with `threadB.Start()'.

Comment: I'm sure checked now again .

Comment: Ok changed it to B the second one now it's working but still same problem slow and stuttering when move windows around the screen drag them . It's not that my program need or that i need to drag windows around the screen but if i want to move a window to another places just not to see it in the middle of screen it's all moving slow and stuttering and not only the Form1 every window of any application even if i'm dragging around a web site window to put in the lower right bottom corner for example .

Comment: Then how about doing a performance profiling session? Check if you have it in Visual Studio (in menu Analysis, in 2012).

Comment: You may also want to increase the sleep duration for the thread that's pushing to ffmpeg to something that would give you the desired framerate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which one takes longer: `ScreenCapture.CaptureScreen` or `ffmp.PushFrame(bitmap)`. Since it's a bitmap, I'm assuming that ffmp can't be that fast and it eats up some time.

I'd go with a Producer/Consumer approach. You have thread A which does screenshots, pushes them to a `ConcurrentQueue` and from there they're picked up by thread B which pushes them to ffmp.

Some sample code (not tested, nor guaranteed to be fully working so probably you'll have to do a few adjustments):

```
//We need this thread for cross-thread access, so we don't want it cached. 
private volatile bool _workersEnabled;
private ConcurrentQueue<Bitmap> _imageBuffer;

public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ffmp = new Ffmpeg();
  sc = new ScreenCapture();

  _workersEnabled = false; 
  _imageBuffer = new ConcurrentQueue<Bitmpap>();

  threadA = new Thread(CaptureScreensEntryPoint);
  threadB = new Thread(ConsumeScreensEntryPoint);
}

private void StartRecording_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _workersEnabled = true; 
  threadA.Start();
  threadB.Start();

  //Disable the button, so we eliminate the possibility to start this twice (would throw an exception anyway).
  StartRecording.Enabled = false;
}

private void CaptureScreensEntryPoint() 
{
  while(_workersEnabled)
  {
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)ScreenCapture.CaptureScreen(true);

    //just add it to the queue.
    _imageBuffer.Enqueue(bitmap);

    //wait a bit
    Thread.Sleep(40);
  }
}

private void ConsumeScreensEntryPoint() 
{
  while(_workersEnabled)
  {
    Bitmap workItem = null;
    if(_imageBuffer.TryDequeue(out workItem))
    { 
      ffmp.PushFrame(workItem);
      workItem.Dispose();
    }

    //Also wait a bit here. Don't want to eat up the entire processor.
    Thread.Sleep(10);
  }
}
```

Make sure to set `_workersEnabled` to `false` when you want to stop the workers, for example when the form closes, or maybe you have a dedicated button for that. You may also want to add some error handling and make the sleep periods configurable for both threads.

---

**Note**

I suppose I could've done it with TPL but this was somewhat quicker to post. Feel free to adjust the solution or post a new one.

Comment: marceln i'm getting an error on the threadA.Start(); line . i will update my question now please take a loot on it .

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the capture code in a separate thread.  I've done something similar for a desktop capture application and was able to get around 60 FPS.